# Hide <li> when total is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am getting some values from MySQL through JSON and using them to do some totals.

example:

```
time_tot = time_st + time_mo;
```

And then I am trying to see if the total is 0, otherwise I do some process.  However it seems that when the value is 0, the first part of the IF does not work.  On the other hand, if the total is >0 the else works fine.

```
if (time_tot == 0) { 
// hide image             
} else {
// do process
}
```

I have tried various options such as the following but none seem to work:

```
if (time_tot == 0) 
if (time_tot === 0)
if (time_tot == "0")
if (time_tot === "0")
```

I have also tried to change the value to integer however that did not work either:

```
time_tot = parseInt(time_st + time_mo);
if (time_tot = 0) {
```

Anyone has any idea how this can be done or point at any issues I have in my code?

**UPDATED:**

HTML:

```
<li>Total Time: <span id="totalTime"></span>hrs</li>
<li class="imagePlaceholder"><div id="image"></div></li>
```

JS:

```
if (time_tot == 0) { 
// hide image  
$('.imagePlaceholder').addClass('display_none');         
} else {
// do process
}
```

CSS:

```
.display_none { display:none; }
```

Comment: Before the `if` statement, add `console.log(time_tot + " " + (typeof time_tot));`

Comment: Did you try `alert(time_tot)` or `console.log(time_tot)`...

Comment: Check `typeof time_tot` before you do any processing. It's probably a string.

Comment: In your last example you use `parseInt` without a radix, and then you do an assignment in the `if` statement. Surely those are typos?

Comment: How are you connecting to your database (PHP I assume)? You can use jquery's ajax function to connect to your server page, retrieve the information you are looking for, and then do something if the request is successful. It seems like that is pretty close to what you are trying to do. Here is a link to the Ajax function, and please let me know if you have questions on how to implement it. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Additionally, have you tried alerting your value for time_tot? What is that value so you can see how the comparison is working?

Comment: We are going to need to see the data that is in `time_st` and `time_mo`.  Are they strings, numbers, objects, etc?

Comment: yes I am connecting to the database using ajax.  I am getting the results back fine, it's just I cannot understand whether once I make the addition whether the value stored inside time_tot is a string or integer.

Comment: @kojiro  had a typo above.  Updated

Comment: @Pointy I tried the typeof now and it showed "number"

Comment: I think most of these comments are barking up the wrong tree. If both `a` and `b` are the string `"0"`, then `a + b == "00"`, but in JavaScript, `"00" == 0`, so at least one of the cases you tried should've worked.

Comment: It seems like an obvious thing to say but are you sure the bit in your if that you say doesn't work is syntactically correct, etc. Have you tried replacing that block with a simple alert to confirm, etc.

Comment: The title has "Hide `<li>`" but that seems irrelevant to the body of the question.  Might there be a better title for this question?

Comment: What does `console.log(time_st, time_mo, time_tot);` output?

Comment: If it's a number and it's zero, then the `if` statement **must** work.  What makes you think it doesn't?  I suspect you've identified the wrong piece of code as the source of whatever problem you're having.

Comment: I tried to set class="display_none" on the <li> directly however it did not hide even though the css is good and is there.  Is it possible to hide <li> elements?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Use Firebug or the Chrome debugger to investigate why that CSS rule is being overridden.

Comment: Issue solved.  See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason adding the class display_none did not work.

I solved the issue by changing my JS to the following and it worked perfectly.  The issue was not related to whether time_tot was 0 or not, but rather the process after the IF.

```
$('.imagePlaceholder').hide();
```

Comment: I guess the reason why adding the display_none class didn't work is related with [CSS specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity). There is probably another CSS rule conflicting with your display:none . If your are using a modern web browser for development, you must have some means to check this by inspecting the CSS that ends up being applied to that element(s).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest parsing your values to numbers. (Based on your code sample, I assume that you are only expecting integer values, not floats.)

```
var time_tot = parseInt(time_st, 10) + parseInt(time_mo, 10);

if (time_tot === 0) { 
  // show message           
} else {
  // do process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the integers individually.

```
var t1 = parseInt(time_st);
var t2 = parseInt(time_mot);

var time_tot = t1+t2;

if (time_tot === 0){
}
```

Also in your code you have the variable being written in the if condition make sure you're not actually doing that.